# How to use google maps API V2 on Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I did the following operation:
-Download Google play service for Android SDK

-Import google-play-services_lib from SDK folder

-Add this like lib on my app

-Take my SHA1 code form ecplipse windows/preferences/android/build

-Create new project on Google APIs Console;

-Take my API code with: SHA1 code and project's pakage name

-Add permission on manifest:

```
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" />
```

and

```
    <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="mykey" />
```

on application tag
-create new xml file with this code:

```
         <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

and new activity with this(it's not in main activity):

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

    public class Map extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);

    }

    }
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: you never described a problem that you are having

Comment: Yea man, gotta actually tell us your symptoms, or we can't prescribe you the proper meds.

Comment: I didn't described my problem beacuse i believe there were a syntactic problems. Pavel sayed the right things, i'm missing meta-data...

Comment: which package name you used to generate api key in api console? either general package name or package name which is present in manifest file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would ask what is the problem you have?:) we are not telepats..
From what I can see here, I would say you are missing another 'meta' attribute for the play services, but this would be reported into logcat:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

So whats the actual problem? Is it crashing, just blank map, whats the logcat output?

Also some people try to add play services .jar file instead of referencing the project. This leads to crash as well